# Occupational Prestige Measures

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for data where occupational prestige has been measured. I would like to analyze data over time to see, if occupational prestige of different jobs changes over time. If you don't know of any primary data sources, you may have an idea of what data indirectly measures occupational prestige.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_prestige links to:

PRESTIGE SCORES FOR ALL DETAILED CATEGORIES IN THE 1980 CENSUS OCCUPATIONAL CLASSIFICATION
[http://ibgwww.colorado.edu/~agross/NNSD/prestige%20scores.html](http://ibgwww.colorado.edu/%7Eagross/NNSD/prestige%20scores.html)

The data is from 1989 in the USA.
No data license information is listed.

Top of the list:

```
Occupation  Prestige
Physicians  86.05
Lawyer  74.77
Computer systems analyst or scientist   73.70
Teacher     73.51
Physicist or astronomer     73.48
Chemist     73.33
Architects  73.15
Biological or life scientist    73.14
Physical scientist, not elsewhere classified    73.09
Chemical engineer   72.30
Professor   71.79
Judge   71.49
Engineer (not elsewhere classified)     70.69
Chief executive or general administrator, public administration     70.45
Geologist or geodesist  69.75
Psychologist    69.39
Manager, medicine and health    69.22
Aerospace engineer  69.22
Clergy  68.96
Civil engineer  68.81
```